# Multi line text in email Body

Tags: javascript, http

i try to get some details from dynamics crm (Phonecall entity) and to make this information in a body from an email. the problem is when have a multi line in the "description Field",  all the text will in one line wrote in the email body(see pictures). can anyone help me Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBZOv.jpg)

```
function TriggerOutlook()

{
//get the form value
var form=Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
//if the form is saved  
 if(form==2)
   {    

        // get the end date            
        var scheduledend = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("actualend").getValue();                    
        var date =scheduledend.toString();
        var date_split = date.split(' ');
        switch(date_split[1])
        {
            case "Jan":
            var month="01";
            break;
            case "Feb":
            var month="02";
            break;
            case "Mar":
            var month="03";
            break;
            case "Apr":
            var month="04";
            break;
            case "May":
            var month="05";
            break;
            case "Jun":
            var month="06";
            break;
            case "Jul":
            var month="07";
            break;
            case "Aug":
            var month="08";
            break;
            case "Sep":
            var month="09";
            break;
            case "Okt":
            var month="10";
            break;
            case "Nov":
            var month="11";
            break;
            case "Dec":
            var month="12";
            break;



        }
        var end_Time=month+"/"+date_split[2]+"/"+date_split[3] ;


        var sub=Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subject").getValue() ;
        //get the description 
        var description = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").getValue();          


        //get the required Value
        var required  = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("to").getValue();


        //test of the empty fields
      if (end_Time == null)
        {
            end_Time="";
        }
      if(description == null)
        {
            description="";
        }


         if( required==null || required=="")

        {
            required="";

        }
        else
        {
            var required_name=required[0].name;
           var  required_id=required[0].id.toLowerCase();

        }

        // trigger the Outlook
            var subject=required_name+", "+ sub ;

            var body = "End Time:" + end_Time + escape('\n') + "Account:" + required_name +escape('\n') + "Contact:" + escape('\n') + "Description:" + description;       
            window.location.href = "mailto:?body="+body+"&subject="+subject;               

    }

}
```

Comment: `escape()` is deprecated, you should use `encodeURIComponent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `description`, just like you escape all the explicit newlines in the URL.

Rather than call `escape()` on each part when you're concatenating, concatenate everything and then escape the whole thing.

You should use `encodeURIComponent()` rather than the obsolete `escape()`.

```
var subject = encodeURIComponent(required_name + ", " + sub);
var body = encodeURIComponent("End Time:" + end_Time + '\n' + "Account:" + required_name + '\n' + "Contact:" + '\n' + "Description:" + description);
```